# French/US citizen traveling on expired passport

Tags: usa, passports, france, dual-nationality, expired

My daughter is a US and French citizen. We leave in a couple of days for France and realized her passports for both countries are expired. We are going from the US to France. She has her National ID card for France which isn’t expired and is accepted for entry into France through passport exemptions. What I can’t figure out is if she will be able to board the plane without a valid passport?

We have a solution for returning to the US so aren’t concerned about that. Only getting through security and on the plane to get to France.

Comment: What airline is operating the flight?

Comment: How old is your daughter?

Comment: See also [Can you travel to the EU with an expiring US passport + EU identification card?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176974/can-you-travel-to-the-eu-with-an-expiring-us-passport-eu-identification-card)

Comment: @xngtng in that question the OP had a *valid* US passport. In this question the OP has no valid passports at all.

Comment: If you’re still around, we would love to hear what you did/what happened. Did you attempt the trip? If so, was she able to travel?

Answer (score 3):

The places where checks happen are:

- During check-in. Airlines are required to check that you have the necessary documents to enter the destination country, and in the case of the US, to report that you were in board (and left the country).

  You can enter France with just a national ID card, but I would be surprised if the airline accepted it in this situation. Don’t have any evidence either way though.
- At the TSA checkpoint. You can actually travel without any ID at all, there’s a special process for that, but it takes a lot longer (IIRC they advise 2 hours). Bring the expired US passport and any other form of identification, especially anything with a picture. Of course if she’s a minor she doesn’t actually need any ID, but if she’s close to 18 any way to prove it is useful.
- Upon arrival in France, where a national ID card is sufficient.

So it all boils down to the airline accepting the national ID card. You may try to call them to see what they say (or hop to the airport today and ask at a check-in desk).

The alternative is to get an emergency passport, but there are conditions for that, and if you are leaving tomorrow it’s probably extremely tight.

In any case if you do try it, you should budget a lot more time than usual at the airport.

Comment: -1, airline agents are required to follow airline guidance. It is unlikely that the op would be allowed to board because the airline requires a valid passport. See the guidance references in my answer.

Comment: @littleadv guidance for passengers and actual policy are very different things. I was once greeted at check-in 20 minutes past the limit with “we were waiting for you”, for instance. And the Iata Travel Centre, which is based on Timatic, seems to think that an ID card is enough, and airline policy is usually “do whatever Timatic says”. I’m really not fully convinced it’s possible, but I wouldn’t be that surprised if it worked. Surprised, yes, but not very surprised.

Comment: The op is asking a practical question, not a SCOTUS level discussion that some people here like so much. We don't know what an actual gate agent *might* do, but I told the OP with a high level of certainty and reliable references what the airlines *require*.

Answer (score 1):

Passport is required for international air travel to and from the US, and US citizens are required by law to bear a valid US passport when they leave the country (See [8 USC 1185(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1185)). Bearing an expired passport to satisfy that requirement may count as a misuse of passport, a felony ([18 USC 1544](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1544)).

Example from the [American Airlines guidance](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/international-travel/international-travel.jsp):

> A passport is required for all international travel. If you're traveling anywhere overseas, you need a passport to board an international flight and to enter the country.

Similarly, from [Delta](https://www.delta.com/us/en/check-in-security/required-travel-documents/travel-from-the-us) (highlighted at source):

> When you’re traveling outside of the United States, make sure you have all required travel documents. **A passport is required for all international travel**.

While you may get lucky and the airline agent would let you board without any passport at all (highly unlikely on its own), the troubles will start long before that - at the checkin and the TSA security check.

Comment: US citizens are not required to use their US passport to leave the US, only to "bear" it.  In the discussions about whether a national ID is sufficient, the fact that there is no valid US passport might come up, but it might not.

Comment: Where it is written that a passport is requiered for air travel?

Comment: Hundreds of thousands of people fly without passports every day — domestic flights, internal Schengen flights, and so on.

Comment: @phoog good luck arguing semantics with an overworked gate agent

Comment: @littleadv I've flown out of the US dozens of times without showing my US passport to anyone and without being asked for it.  Gate agents are not charged with enforcing 8 USC 1185(b) and they don't enforce it.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella the US generally requires all departing and arriving international passengers to have a passport.  There are some exceptions, but these do not include national ID cards.  There's a story somewhere on this site about a woman (Swedish if I recall correctly) who managed to talk her way onto a flight home with her ID after her passport was lost or stolen in the US (relieving her of the need to get an emergency passport), but this case is different in two significant respects. OP might get lucky, but I wouldn't count on it; an emergency passport would be better, if time permits.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella here's the implementation guide for the US advance passenger information system: https://www.cbp.gov/document/guides/unedifact-implementation-guide -- note in "table 12" that the only foreign document listed is a passport.  I've always wondered how the airline reported the departure of the woman with the stolen passport.

Comment: @phoog did you not show *any* passport?

Comment: @phoog table 12 lists documents for immigration purposes. Table 6, which describes records for international departures, refers to table 12, but also says “normally, report a passport…” and states the reference standard is PAXSLT which in turn defines document types as coming from ICAO 9303 (the spec for machine readable travel documents), so anything that appears in an MRZ can at least be described here. No idea if it will actually be accepted (or even if there is any feedback on departure like the board/no board responses for inbound passengers), though.

Comment: @littleadv I showed my non-US passport.

Comment: @phoog goodie, so you still had to show *a* passport. The OP doesn't have *any* passport.

Comment: Right. But the statement "US citizens are required by law to use valid US passport to enter and leave the country" is incorrect.  Thanks for retracting it.  Are you aware of anyone who has been charged under 18 USC 1544 for traveling with an expired passport?  I doubt it.

Comment: @phoog it's one of these statutes that gets added on top of other charges, so if the OP is doing something nefarious then it will be just one more charge on the long rap sheet. That said, the fact that you don't immediately get sent to jail for any violation doesn't make it any less of a violation. In any case, this is an irrelevant discussion to the OP, and as I mentioned in my other comment - this is not Law@SE and the OP wants a practical answer, not a SCOTUS-level legal discussion.

Comment: @jcaron look at pages 102 and following for another description of the valid document types for PAXLST segment Group 5 DOC.  It's the same set that does not include foreign national ID cards.